# Realtime Notification Concepts

Tags: ajax, real-time

I want to create realtime notification 
I dont want use node js

by the way I have ajax notification .
Its load 1s 1 time working Its right way

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieved real-time notification goal. One of the most famous and easy to use library for implementing more effectively notification scenario is **SignalR**.
According to [Asp.net](https://www.asp.net/signalr) definition:

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events), grouping connections, and authorization.

See:
[SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) , [SignalR.net](http://signalr.net/)